# function not returning variable value in a string

Tags: php, function, variables, return

The function below is working fine, but not returning the value for only the variable `$field` in the string given to `$reslt`:

```
function req($slice,$field)
{
   if ($slice == "") {
      $reslt =  $field. ' cannot be empty<br />'; 
      return $reslt;
   }else{
      $reslt = "";
      return $reslt;
   }
}
req($slice,$field);
$err_mess = req();
echo $err_mess; // gives me 'cannot be empty' as result but does not show the value for the '$field' variable included in the string
```

Comment: that means your $field variable is also empty

Comment: @Surace no it isn't, i have checked, it is got value

Comment: Should there be a period (.) after $field in the fourht line? $reslt =  $field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
req($slice,$field);
$err_mess = req();
```

you are calling your function twice: once discarding the result, the second time without parameters.

I reckon you need

```
$err_mess = req($slice, $field);
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the parameters did it, but one quick question, why do you say i am calling the function twice. Am only calling the function once, second time i am trying to get the return result into a variable

Comment: @Manu, that's not how it works. Read the [paragraph on functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) in the PHP manual again.

Comment: can you please tell me the best way to return the $reslt variable to $err_mess the right way ... I have already gone through the document you provided, the exixting code is the besti could come up with

Comment: Exactly how I describe in my answer.